# Trouble after deploying war to tomcat using chef

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra

I'm deploying war file to Tomcat using chef, and then tomcat can't unzip war file.
If I'm deploying the same war file using wget from Dropbox all works.

My cookbook 'copy war file'

```
file '/opt/tomcat/webapps/MyApp.war' do
    content 'MyApp.war'
end
```

And tomcat logs:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/MyApp.war
Oct 16, 2015 1:04:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig beforeStart
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/MyApp]
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:154)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:91)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:373)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Oct 16, 2015 1:04:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5089)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Oct 16, 2015 1:04:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyApp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5270)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

Oct 16, 2015 1:04:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/MyApp.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyApp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please advice me how correctly to deploy war file to Tomcat using chef.

Comment: You're writing a file named MyApp.war with as content the litteral string 'MyApp.war', not surprising this is not a zip file and tomcat complain... [read the doc](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html#properties)

Comment: You should not store large binary files in cookbooks and better use a remote file ressource targeting an artifact repository over http for example

Comment: Thanks. I had to use: "cookbook_file " and "source"